# Uno to NodeMCU Serial Connection Problem

Tags: arduino-uno, nodemcu, softwareserial

This is my first project with any sort of development board and it has been a blast so far.

I am running into some issues, however, while trying to send serial data from my Uno to a NodeMCU board.

I have the following connections:

Uno Rx to NMcu Tx

Uno Tx to NMcu Rx

Uno GND to NMcu GND

microUSB from computer to power NMcu

usb from computer to power Uno

**EDIT:** after some suggestions, I have also tried the following.

Uno DigitalPin 5 to NMcu D6

Uno DigitalPin 6 to NMcu D5

Uno GND to NMcu GND

microUSB from computer to power NMcu

usb from computer to power Uno

With the following code:

```
// UNO sender Code
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial toESP(0, 1); //Rx, Tx (also tried 5,6)

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  toESP.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("sending");
  toESP.println("message from Nano");
  delay(1000);
}
```

---

```
// NodeMCU receiver code
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial fromNano(3, 2); //Rx, Tx (also tried D5, D6)

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  fromNano.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  if (fromNano.available())
  {
    char inChar = fromNano.read();
    Serial.print(inChar);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("not available");
  }
  delay(2000);
}
```

I can pull up a serial monitor from both and see the UNO sending data (the TX led also blinks on the uno).

The NodeMCU code never satisfies the `fromNano.available` condition.

Is there anything I am overlooking that is causing this not to work? I've attached a picture of my connections as well.

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: 0 and 1 are hardware Serial pins in Uno and 3 is a hardware Serial pin on NodeMcu so you should not use it for SoftwareSerial. and the wires are on pins 1 and 3 on NodeMcu (hardware Serial pins)

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the response. I tried using other digital pins on the arduino and nodemcu (and made sure to update the corresponding code) the other night, but didn't have any luck. I tried something like SoftwareSerial(5,6) for the sender (arduino) and SoftwareSerial(D5,D6) for the receiver (nodeMCU). Making sure that arduino digital pin 5 is connected to nodemcu D6, and vice versa. I'll try again later tonight.

Comment: @Juraj - After trying on digital pins 5,6 on the arduino, and D5,D6 on the nodemcu, I still cannot receive serial data. fromNano.available() is always false. I've set both to 9600 baud rate. https://imgur.com/a/gfVo2nt

Answer (score 2):

Arduino UNO is using pin 0 and pin 1 to have serial with USB serial Communication. You can not use them to softserial. Change softserial to other pins.  /Mikael

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is it fine to just use any other digital pins to initialize the SoftwareSerial?

Comment: I tried digital pins 2 and 3 (and also 5,6) for RX,TX respectively and it didn't seem to solve the issue. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Why do use 2 serial conections, you only need one.

Comment: I'm only using one serial connection between the boards from my understanding. I just tried on pairs (2,3) and (5,6) independently for troubleshooting.

Comment: In the code you are using two.

Comment: Are you referring to Serial vs SoftwareSerial? I am including a Serial channel to debug via the monitor in Arduino IDE

Comment: Is the Arduino 5V or 3V? The NodeMcu is not always 5V tollerant. Try to remove the USB connection from the Arduino then connect 3V from NodeMcu to 5V on the Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

@Carlmikael is definitely correct in his answer, I should not have been using hardware pins with softwareserial.

Besides that problem, my issue was resolved ultimately when I noticed that if I powered up the NodeMCU before powering up the Arduino, everything worked as expected.

Maybe someone can elaborate as to why this caused an issue?